# Java NIO Selector.open() IOException

Tags: java, nio, ioexception

Whilst using the `java.nio.channels.Selector` object I can't help but notice that the factory creation method `Selector.open()` throws an IOException.

Aside from being a pain to handle yet another IOException, I don't get how opening the selector can possibly be an I/O operation not to mention somehow fail at it and throw an IOException.

The code inside the Selector class to open is as follows:

```
public static Selector open() throws IOException {
    return SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
}
```

noting that it defers to the `SelectorProvider` object I went to look at the code for openSelector(). As follows:

```
public abstract AbstractSelector openSelector()
    throws IOException;
```

Looks like the class is being loaded dynamically at runtime which puts even more mystery to how these Selectors are being constructed.

The class responsible for creating the Selector if "dynamic loading" fails is `sun.nio.ch.DefaultSelectorProvider` which I don't have the source code for, so thats as far I can I go in terms of tracing the source of the IOException.

Java's javadoc on Selectors do not help at all they merely state:

> Throws: IOException - If an I/O error occurs

If anyone has any insight regarding this bazaar IOException created by Selector.open() please let me know. Additionally answer a more practical question, should the IOException be "properly" handled (e.g. messagebox, flashing lights, toolkit beep sounds, etc) or just tucked away in a log/empty catch block.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that it's platform and implementation specific, so you pretty much have no choice; you should catch it and deal with it. And since it's going to be a really rare event (after which you won't have a `Selector`), it's probably a bells-and-whistles thing. Option B is ignore it and let it hit the top of the stack and halt things.

The long answer is that on Linux, with the current default implementation, it's not going to throw. If it's >= 2.6 kernel, `openSelector()` is going to instantiate and return a `EPollSelectorImpl`. If it's < 2.6 you get a `PollSelectorImpl`. Neither of those class's constructors throws an `IOException`.

On Windows, however, you get a `WindowsSelectorImpl` whose constructor *does* throw `IOException`.  I'd have to dig deeper to find out what would cause it but obviously something can.

Again though, it's an implementation detail, so it could always change in the future.

You can pull the complete source for the openjdk to look at the source for those classes.

Comment: Thanks for the information. They should really give some reasons when arbitrarily hooking up random exceptions. Implementation-specific or not, saying that this method may throw an IOException when `an I/O error occurs` is not good enough. Anyway, I'm too lazy to pull source code for this. If you however do find anything, please do update your answer with this information. Should no new information arrive from anyone else, I'll accept this after a while.

Answer (score 2):

It allows the implementation to throw IOExceptions for reasons which naturally aren't specified at the API level. For example, the Windows implementation of `Selector` uses a selection tree whose internal nodes are pipes to handle cases where the number of selectable channels exceeds the Windows maximum. So the Selector has to be able to open a pipe, and this can fail.

Comment: Seems like everyone is blaming the Windows implementation for this. I know this goes beyond the question but do you know of any other implementation which could throw such an exception? I'll handle it appropriately, that for sure but I'm curious to see how setting up a selector channel is done on other implementations.

Comment: I'm not 'blaming the Windows implementation' for anything. The implementation, whatever it is, could encounter an error creating a selector, whatever that means on the platform, and so it has to be able to throw an exception, so the designers chose IOException, logically enough.